# Requesting historical and future traffic flow data

Tags: json, xml, google-maps, here-api

I am searching for a possible source that can give me historical and future traffic flow data at a given coordinate.

I tried that in Nokia Here Map with below URL. It seems to me that time giving is not functional.
Does anyone know where can I get that kind of information?

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=app_id&app_code=app_code&linkAttributes=dynamicSpeedInfo&waypoint=geo!48.7840385,9.1789398&time=2016-10-10T12:00:00Z
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but you can just add the `departure_time` parameter to [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) or [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro). "The default traffic model, best_guess, returns the most likely travel time given everything that’s known about the traffic conditions—both the historical model for the queried time and day of the week, and the actual live traffic conditions right now."

Comment: Try reading this blog about [Predicting the Future with Google Maps APIs](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/11/predicting-future-with-google-maps-apis.html) I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Routing service supports this use case. Please have a look at the documentation here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/enabling-traffic.html